Yii2 PHP framework only my composer classes are being loaded
I am building a aplication with Yii2 framework but I am experiencing a problem I have never seen in PHP.
If I try loading any local classes that I have created I get this error "maximum execution time of 125 seconds exceeded".
I have tried increasing script execution time nothing, I have tried increasing memory nothing.
Everything was working find and suddenly this issue stated.
This problem of why only composer classes are being loaded and my local classes won't is bigger than me.
If anyone is familiar with this problem and have a solution I would greatly appreciate any help I can get.
I am using Yii2 namespace for loading local classes

Please share more details, like the code involved. What do you mean by "Composer classes"? And how is this problem related to Javascript?
